# siunitx Inserting Comma After Period

Tags: siunitx

I'd like to use commas as the thousand separator, but `siunitx` is inserting a comma after the period that is used for decimal separation. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{y}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 3}

\begin{document}
     \SI{9000}[\$]{\per\tonne}
     
     \SI{0.1339}{\per\year}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> $9,000 t<sup>-1</sup>
>
> 0.133,9 y<sup>-1</sup>

If I don't set the option `group-minimum-digits` to `3`, I don't get `9,000`. But it ends up displaying `0.133,9`. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `group-digits = integer`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{y}
\sisetup{group-digits = integer, group-minimum-digits = 3, group-separator = {,}}

\begin{document}
     \SI{9000}[\$]{\per\tonne}

     \SI{0.1339}{\per\year}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And distinct group separators for the integral and the decimal part is not supported. It wouldn't make sense anyway.

Comment: @egreg To-date no-one has asked! I doubt it would make much sense :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow... you helped me in less than a minute after I posted. I love this community! :)